# Private variables during debugging

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__whiteList = self.readFile('whiteList.txt')
        a = 0 # Breakpoint

    def getWhiteList(self):
        return self.__whiteList
```

Well, I placed a breakpoint at `a = 0`.

When I stop at the breakpoint, I want to evaluate `__whiteList`.

The error is:

```
AttributeError:'Controller' object has no attribute '__whiteList'
```

Well, this is a mystery to me. Because I have the getter method and outside the class it works perfectly.

Well, you may tell me that I could easily take no notice of it as it works outside the class. But I need it during the debugging.

Could you comment on why I can't catch the value at the breakpoint?

Comment: Double underscores invoke name mangling, you need `instance._Controller__whiteList` (or, better, use a single underscore and read [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you prefix an attribute name with a double underscore, Python ["mangles" the name](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) by placing `_<classname>` before it.  This means that you would need to do:

```
def getWhiteList(self):
    return self._Controller__whiteList
```

in order to access the `__whiteList` attribute.

But it doesn't look like you should be using the `__` in the first place.  You may just want to remove it and access `whiteList` directly:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.whiteList = self.readFile('whiteList.txt')
    a = 0 # Breakpoint

def getWhiteList(self):
    return self.whiteList
```

Or, you could use a single underscore:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._whiteList = self.readFile('whiteList.txt')
    a = 0 # Breakpoint

def getWhiteList(self):
    return self._whiteList
```

This sends a clear message that the `_whiteList` attribute is internal and should not be accessed directly from outside the class under normal circumstances.

Also, if you decide to use either of these approaches, then there is really no purpose to your `getWhiteList` method since you can access the `whiteList` attribute directly.  I would remove it.  You generally want to avoid getters and setters in Python since 99% of the time they do nothing but clutter the class definition.

Comment: ... and remove the now unnecessary `getWhiteList` method.

Comment: A getter can return the value but not allow you to change it - they are still a good thing in python.

Comment: @dgunchev - In that case, you could make `whiteList` a `@property` and make its `setter` function raise an error.  I'm saying that `get_attribute` and `set_attribute` methods are considered ugly in Python.

Comment: @iCodez Yes, you can. The property can also be read only one. Exposing the contents of a class member bu making it "public" gives you read and write access. But this all is offtopic, the question was how to get the value :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print self.getWhiteList()` or `print self._Controller__whiteList`.

```
-> a = 0 # Breakpoint
(Pdb) list
  1     class Controller:
  2  
  3         def __init__(self):
  4             self.__whiteList = self.readFile('whiteList.txt')
  5 B->         a = 0 # Breakpoint
  6  
  7         def getWhiteList(self):
  8             return self.__whiteList
  9  
 10         def readFile(self, x):
 11             return x
(Pdb) print self
<__main__.Controller instance at 0x106d200>
(Pdb) print self.getWhiteList()
whiteList.txt
(Pdb) print self._Controller__whiteList
whiteList.txt
```